# heatmap.2 function from gplots in R shows histogram key, heatmap and dendogram separately

Tags: r, heatmap, gplots

I am trying to plot a heat map with the function heatmap.2 from gplots library in R. The main problem is it generates three independent plots separately, whilst it previously worked well. It seems as if something in the library had changed, but I've been playing around a lot and can't find any solution. Did anyone experience the same issue?

Comment: This works fine `heatmap.2(matrix(1:10,2))`

Comment: I've tried that and still fails... i get the plots separately

Comment: Reinstall the package and/or R.